# Unable to delete folder using SPFarm User Also

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can anyone please help me for below issue.

I create a Folder using VS 2010. but one folder is creating a issue. it can't be deleted,renamed and i can't upload even a document in it.  i am a site collection administrator. I checked it is not Check out. I can't do anything with that Folder using Farm admin as well.

Your needful reply will be appreciable. Code is

```
public static void AssignFolderPermission(ref SPWeb web, ref SPDocumentLibrary _MyDocLibrary, ref string fPath, ref SPFieldUserValueCollection users, string PermissionLevel, bool bri, bool createFolder)
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPGroupCollection grps = web.SiteGroups;
        SPFolderCollection _MyFolders = web.Folders;
        SPFolder curFolder = web.GetFolder(fPath);
        if (curFolder.Exists == false && createFolder == true)
        {
            curFolder = _MyFolders.Add(fPath);
            _MyDocLibrary.Update();
        }

        if (curFolder.Exists == true)
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            curFolder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(bri);
            //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            //RemoveGroupPermission(curFolder, grps);
            //_MyDocLibrary.Update();

            SPGroup grp1 = grps[" Group_ Inc"];
            SPRoleAssignment SpRoleAss = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)grp1);
            SpRoleAss.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Full Control"]);
            curFolder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(SpRoleAss);

            grp1 = grps["Executives"];
            SpRoleAss = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)grp1);
            SpRoleAss.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]);
            curFolder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(SpRoleAss);

            string dept = "";

            if (web.Url.ToLower().Contains("hr"))
                dept = "hr";               
            else if (web.Url.ToLower().Contains("sales"))
                dept = "sales";

            if (dept.Trim() != "")
            {
                grp1 = grps[dept + "Executives"];
                SpRoleAss = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)grp1);
                SpRoleAss.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Executive"]);
                curFolder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(SpRoleAss);

                grp1 = grps[dept + "Users"];
                SpRoleAss = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)grp1);
                SpRoleAss.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["View Only"]);
                curFolder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(SpRoleAss);

                grp1 = grps["Viewers"];
                SpRoleAss = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)grp1);
                SpRoleAss.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["View Only"]);
                curFolder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(SpRoleAss);
            }

            foreach (var userName in users)
            {
                SPUser SpUser = null;

                foreach (SPGroup grp in grps)
                {
                    SPUserCollection grpUsers = grp.Users;
                    try
                    {
                        SpUser = grpUsers[userName.User.LoginName];
                        break;
                    }
                    catch { }
                }

                if (SpUser != null)
                {
                    SpRoleAss = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)SpUser);
                    SpRoleAss.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions[PermissionLevel]);
                    curFolder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(SpRoleAss);
                    //_MyDocLibrary.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }




        fPath = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + title + "/5.1 Contracts";
                    AssignFolderPermission(ref web, ref _MyDocLibrary, ref fPath, ref users, "View Only", false, true);

                    fPath = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + title + "/5.1 Contracts/5.1.1 Contract Docs";
                    AssignFolderPermission(ref web, ref _MyDocLibrary, ref fPath, ref users, "Employees", false, true);
```

Sometimes Getting exception " Exception calling "BreakRoleInheritance" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot complete this action."

Thanks

Comment: I think it would help, if you provide more information how you create the folder with VS. I think there is the problem

Comment: Plese see, I have update my post

Comment: I have read an article about this problem and they said "If we instantiate two separate SPWeb objects for single site, it will throw 'Cannot complete this action.  Please try again' error. So ensure that single web object is currently in use."

btw you set AllowUnsafeUpdates to true twice